# SXA move cloned items

Tags: sxa

I have some items that were cloned under experience accelerator folder under Feature node. But i am afraid that they got overwritten after upgrade of SXA to any newer version.

Can i move those items to another folder and this will require to move also items created in branch templates,...? or it will be preferred to redo the cloning again under the correct folder?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create items under SXA item or modify SXA items as they will be overridden by SXA while upgrading. Just like you noticed it.

You need to create your project folders and put those items there. Take a look:

[image]

Comment: So can i move the already created items to the new folder i created or this can cause any issues to the already cloned ones?

Comment: I don't know what have you been cloning and if you created any delegated areas or not. Just try to move and check if everything is working fine.

Comment: While moving IDs of items are not changed so fingers crossed that everything will be fine.

Comment: ok I will give it a try and make sure that everything is going fine